# Push billions of records spread across CSV files in s3 to MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bigdata

I have an s3 bucket, which gets almost 14-15 Billion records spread across 26000csv files, every day.

I need to parse these files and push it to mongo db.

Previously with just 50 to 100 million records, I was using bulk upsert with multiple parallel processes in an ec2 instance and it was fine. But since the number of records increased drastically,  previous method is not that efficient.

So what will be the best method to do this?

Comment: Billions new records every day. What are the specs of your mongodb cluster. Is it sufficiently provisioned, with some spare capacity?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i only need that data for one day, after that i drop the collection. Also although there are billions of data, there will be only 100Million documents, since am updating same _ids. one document may have upto 200 jsons , pushed into an array

Comment: Regardless of data longevity requirements, a disk (spinning rust or ssd) can only sustain a limited number of writes per second. It may very well be that, with 1000x data size, there simply is not enough disks.

Comment: Can you update with the approach you took?

Comment: @GVSandeepI used a multithreaded approach, in which I started an AWS instance (big one 32 core) and started 32 threads, and each thread process data and push to mongo. Keep in mind, our mongo instance was also big which can handle that kind of load

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) which is written in GoLang and can make effective use of threadsto parallelize the uploading. It's pretty fast. you would have to copy the files from S3 to local disk prior to uploading but if you put the node in the same region as the S3 bucket and the database it should run quickly. Also, you could use [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) and its [API](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/) to turn up the IOPS on your cluster while you were loading and dial it down afterwards to speed up uploading.

Comment: I dont think it will work cause, for the records that have same id, i want to update same docuemtn and push some data to its array. Not all data is a document. Even though thereis billions of records, at the end there will be only around 100M docuemnts,

Comment: Ok. In that case, I would pre-split the data and run parallel programs. This will always be more effective than a multi-threaded approach for a large dataset.